# Java Command line option list navigation

Tags: java

I've created a case switch option list,

First option list
option 1 go to option list A 
option 2 go to option list B
option 3 haven't decided what this will do yet C
option 4 Exit

if option 1 is selected
option 1 Do A
option 2 Do B
option 3 Do C
option 4 previous Menu
option 5 Exit

So basically its a switch inside a switch. The bit I'm stuck on is returning to the previous menu.

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose which Sort type to use\n");
        System.out.println("(1): Option 1 - do something\n(2): Option 2 - do something else\n(3): Option 3 - Something Cool\n(4): Exit");
        option = in.nextInt();

        if (option == 4) {
            System.exit(0);
        }


        switch (option) {

        case 1:

            while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose which Sort type to use\n");
        System.out.println("(1): Option 1 - do something\n(2): Option 2 - Do something else\n(3): Option 3 - Something Cool\n(4): Exit");
        option = in.nextInt();

        if (option == 4) {
            System.exit(0);
        }


        switch (option) {

        case 1:

            while (true) {

            System.out.println("Choose which Sort type to use\n");
            System.out.println("(1): Option 1 -something\n(2): Option 2 - something else\n(3): Option 3 - something else\n(4): Option 4 - Previous Menu\n(5): Exit\n");
            option = in.nextInt();
            if (option == 5) {
                System.exit(0);
            }


            switch (option) {

            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

            default:
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid option 1, 2 or 3");
                break;
            }//end of switch


        }//end of while loop





        case 2:
            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Choose which something type to use\n");
                System.out.println("(1): Option 1 - something\n(2): Option 2 - something\n(3): Option 3 - something\n(4): Exit");
                option = in.nextInt();
                if (option == 4) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }


                switch (option) {

                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                case 3:


                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("Please enter a valid option 1, 2 or 3");
                    break;
                }//end of switch


            }//end of while loop











        case 3:

            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid option 1, 2 or 3");
            break;
        }//end of switch

        }
```

Comment: You can use labels and `break <label>;` but it seems to be ugly.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: added, I've removed what the cases actually perform as its not really needed. Lots of sneaky dudes stealing code these days. I was thinking about another if statement, like if option equals 4, go to the start of the code. I've tried googling command line menu's, seems to be surprisingly little, at least things I comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the nested switch inside a method. When you're done with its loop, return.

```
while (true)
{
    option = ...;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 0:
        submenu();
        break;
    // ...
    }
}

// later
public void submenu()
{
    while (true)
    {
        option = ...;
        switch (option)
        {
        case 0:
            return;
            break;
        // ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: only problem with that is the case needs access to stuff inside the main method.EDIT: forgot I need to pass stuff to the method, my bad